# checked not working properly for custom radio/checkboxes

Tags: css

I am trying to make a custom checkbox/radio but the problem is on checked doesn't add css.

My Code:

```css
.custom-checkbox-label {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  .custom-checkbox {
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  input[type='radio'] {
    opacity: 0;
    &:checked {
      .custom-checkbox {
        background: #08abe1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<label htmlFor="delivery-type" className="custom-checkbox-label">
  <div className="custom-checkbox"></div>
  <input
    id="delivery-type"
    type="radio"
    onChange={() => alert(1)}
  />
</label>
```

This is inside React that's why I am using htmlFor, and I did check the radio does get triggered the css inside checked does not apply.

Comment: Are you really using plain CSS or SCSS? That's a huge difference since your `&:checked` selector won't work in CSS but it will work on SCSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things wrong with this -

- `div` is not allowed inside a label - change it to a span
- Your custom checkbox need to come after the input - so you can use the adjacent css selector
- Your sass selector is wrong for the checked (it currently tries to select a custom-checkbox inside your input)
- you need quotes around your `onchange`

```css
/* new sass 
.custom-checkbox-label {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  .custom-checkbox {
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  input[type='radio'] {
    opacity: 0;
    &:checked {
      &+.custom-checkbox {
        background: #08abe1;
      }
    }
  }
}

Which will compile to the below: */

.custom-checkbox-label {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.custom-checkbox-label .custom-checkbox {
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.custom-checkbox-label input[type=radio] {
  opacity: 0;
}

.custom-checkbox-label input[type=radio]:checked+.custom-checkbox {
  background: #08abe1;
}
```

```html
<label htmlFor="delivery-type" className="custom-checkbox-label">
  <input
    id="delivery-type"
    type="radio"
    onChange="{() => alert(1)}"
  />
  <span className="custom-checkbox"></span>
</label>
```